# Output one field of one record from a SQL database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I need to read *one* record from a database (determined by the url's querystring), and take *one* field from it ("Cost"). The SQL currently in my datasource for it is just:

```
SELECT [Cost] from [Cars] WHERE ([RegistrationNumber] = @RegistrationNumber)
```

...then @RegistrationNumber is defined as coming from the QueryString.

I'm very much still learning ASP.NET, so it is likely (I'm hoping) that there's a very simple way to do this. I could use a ListView or something, but I think that's a bit overkill for just one piece of data.

Also, I'm working in C# if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using a `SqlCommand` object to execute your sql, you can use the **[`ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)** method, and it will return the first value from the first row that is returned from the command.

There is an example on the documentation page I linked, but for brevity, I'll include it here:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RegistrationNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@RegistrationNumber"].Value = ** your variable here**;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            double cost = (double)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

That's the "raw" method of running your SQL.  Since you're using a SqlDataSource, that's what it's doing behind the scenes, except it's not using ExecuteScalar() - it's just getting all the data.  You can pick out individual fields using code similar to this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataView dv= (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    foreach (DataRowView dr in dv)
    {
        Label1.Text = dr["Cost"].ToString();
    }
}
```

This would assign the field value to Label1.   If you don't want to have to write any code, it might be easier just to bind it to a simple Repeater control though.

Comment: I haven't done anything SQL-related in C# - it is just a SqlDataSource in my .aspx file.

Comment: Ah I see.  Well you could use a Repeater or a ListView with a simple template, or alternately you could run code in the page_load routine to just pick the value from the datasource and assign it to a label control.  I'll add a bit of code for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are after is [SQLCommand's ExecuteScalar command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx).

So you would use it like this (Disclaimer: I dont really do much in C# with sql databases)

```
Int32 Cost = 0;
SQLCommand sqlcmd = New SQLCommand(SELECT [Cost] from [Cars] WHERE ([RegistrationNumber] = @RegistrationNumber), connection);
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@RegistrationNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RegNumber;
        try
    {
        conn.Open();
        Cost = (Int32)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

That should hopefully work.